# Variable gets written with no intention

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not sure if this is the right place for my question, but I'm dealing with something pretty weird.

In my script, I have a class data() that is just a container for all sorts of constants and sort of data types. One of these data types is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
testStatus = { 'checkpoint': None,
               'tests_Executed': [],
               'tests_Passed': [],
               'tests_FailedFromRegression': [], 
               'tests_FailedFromRetest': [], 
               'tests_PassedFromRetest': [] }
```

My intention is to use this dictionary as a data type for what I call, last test status and current test status. Somewhere in the constructor of my main class, I have something like this:

```
self.lastTestStatus = self.testStatus
self.currentTestStatus = self.testStatus
```

The weird part happens in my run() function of my main class. This is the main worker function of the class. After getting some previously saved status, and building a list with all previously tested items, self.currentTestStatus gets written even if I'm not touching it. The code looks like this:

```
self.getTestStatus()
#All good after this line. 
#This is a function that uses self.lastTestStatus to save the previous status.
#After running this line, self.lastTestStatus["tests_FailedFromRegression"] will hold a list with some items. This is just script testing data.

previouslyTested = []
previouslyTested = self.lastTestStatus["tests_Passed"]
#All good after these two lines.

previouslyTested.extend(self.lastTestStatus["tests_FailedFromRegression"])
#At this point, self.currentTestStatus["tests_Passed"] gets the same value as self.lastTestStatus["tests_FailedFromRegression"] has.

previouslyTested.extend(self.lastTestStatus["tests_FailedFromRetest"])
previouslyTested.extend(self.lastTestStatus["tests_PassedFromRetest"])
```

Any idea what exactly am I doing wrong here? If I use a testStatus2 for my current status, which is identical with testStatus, everything's fine.

I'm using Python 2.7.10 32bit with Spyder 3.0.0dev.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm guessing this is the issure. `self.lastTestStatus` and `self.currentTestStatus` are references to the same object. When you mutate one, you mutate the other, since they are in fact the same object. Instead do `self.lastTestStatus = copy.deepcopy(self.testStatus)` and `self.currentTestStatus = copy.deepcopy(self.testStatus)` in order to copy the dictionary and the lists it holds. https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: For the record, you've kind of thrown the python style guide out the window. We use `lowercase_with_underscores`, not `camelCase` for method names and `obj.getAttrib()` is a big no no in python. Just get the attribute directly `obj.attrib` and use `@property`. This isn't java!

Comment: @FHTMitchell Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I'm not really an expert on Python. How exactly am I'm using obj.getAttrib() in that code? Cheers!

Comment: @FHTMitchell Tested and working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we have an answer ---

`self.lastTestStatus` and `self.currentTestStatus`are references to the same object. When you mutate one, you mutate the other, since they are in fact the same object. Instead do

```
import copy
self.lastTestStatus = copy.deepcopy(self.testStatus)
self.currentTestStatus = copy.deepcopy(self.testStatus)
```

in order to copy the dictionaries and the lists they hold -- [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).